# What has the Haredi reception of Gershom Sholem been like?

Tags: jewish-books, zohar, publications, manuscripts, ownership

I once heard that [Gershom Scholem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershom_Scholem)'s purported rescuing of the Zohar & other works of kabbalah from near extinction was seen as an institutionalized act of thievery by some frum who believed themselves to be the rightful inheritors of various manuscripts, with those who didn't migrate to the Holy Land effectively being divorced from original Sifrei Kodesh of their traditions, at least initially. Haredim are very diverse so I realize that there is no one answer on this, but I'm curious if there are any studies on ownership disputes apropos rabbinical manuscripts, which today often sell for top dollars by prestigious European auction houses, all while several dynasties trace may trace their lineages to the same masters (as is the case with HaGra, for example).

Comment: Would "rabbis" tag be appropriate?

Comment: My ancestors studied Zohar and Kitvei Ari in Poland